# .NET MAUI Picker does not update based on binding context

Tags: maui

I have a view model that populates an ObservableCollection asynchronously using an API call:

```
private ObservableCollection<TestData> _testDataList = new ObservableCollection<TestData>();

public ObservableCollection<TestData> TestDataList
{
    get
    {
        return _testDataList;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_testDataList != value)
        {
            _testDataList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TestDataList");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public TestHistoryViewModel()
{
    client = new HttpClient();
    TestDataList.Add(new TestData());
    GetAllTestDataAsync();
}

private async void GetAllTestDataAsync()
{
    TestDataAPIService testDataAPIService = new TestDataAPIService();
    var testDataList = await testDataAPIService.GetAllTestData();
    TestDataList = AsObservableCollection(testDataList);
}
```

I have a TestData model that includes a field called "FileName":

```
public class TestData
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public TestData()
    {
    }
}
```

And I have a .NET MAUI Picker that is bound to the TestDataList:

```
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Padding="5">
        <Label 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Test History"
            FontSize="Header"/>
        <Picker Title="Select Filename"
                x:Name="FileNamePicker"/>
```

```
public partial class TestHistoryView : ContentView
{
    public TestHistoryView(TestHistoryViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();

        FileNamePicker.ItemsSource = (BindingContext as TestHistoryViewModel).TestDataList;
        FileNamePicker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("FileName");
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the UI is created, the API call has not finished, so when the Picker is created, it is empty. However, despite that fact that it is an ObservableCollection that utilizes binding, the Picker does not update after the API call is complete.

I know, from using the debugger, that the TestDataList of the BindingContext is populated, and the Picker items do not update.

In fact, it never updates until I added this line triggered by a button click:

```
FileNamePicker.ItemsSource = (BindingContext as TestHistoryViewModel).TestDataList;
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers! We ended up using "SetBinding" instead of "ItemsSource" in the TestHistoryView class like this:

```
FileNamePicker.SetBinding(Picker.ItemsSourceProperty, "FileNameList");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maui *might* have carried over an issue from Xamarin.Forms, where some changes to bound properties don't update properly unless done on MainThread.

Safest to wrap in Dispatch call:

```cs
// For an app with a single window, equivalent to `Dispatcher.Dispatch`.
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    TestDataList = AsObservableCollection(testDataList)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to first initialize `TestDataList` as follows:

```
  TestDataList = new ObservableCollection<TestData>();
```

then iterate list `testDataList` you got from `await testDataAPIService.GetAllTestData();` and add the item of it to `TestDataList` one by one.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public TestHistoryViewModel()
{
    client = new HttpClient();
   // TestDataList.Add(new TestData());

     TestDataList = new ObservableCollection<TestData>();
    
    GetAllTestDataAsync();
}

private async void GetAllTestDataAsync()
{
    TestDataAPIService testDataAPIService = new TestDataAPIService();
    List<TestData>  testDataList = await testDataAPIService.GetAllTestData();

    //TestDataList = AsObservableCollection(testDataList);

    foreach (TestData data in testDataList)
    {
       TestDataList.Add(data);
    }

}
```